# Which is the best way to init presenter in MVP-pattern (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mvp

Usually, I write this function to init my presenter from viewController. But I want to use **init()** for making this. What can I do?

ViewController :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  private let viewPresenter = viewPresenter()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.viewPresenter.attachView(controller: self)
  }

  @IBAction func faceBookButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    self.viewPresenter.showLoginWindow()
  }
}
```

ViewPresenter :

```
class ViewPresenter {
  var controller: ViewController?

  func attachView(controller: ViewController) {
    self.controller = controller
  }
}
```

So, If I make this Init in my presenter :

```
let controller: ViewController?
init (controller:ViewController) {
    self.controller = controller
}
```

And try to init like this in viewController:

```
private let viewPresenter = ViewPresenter(controller: self)
```

Xcode give me this error: 
**Cannot convert value of type '(NSObject) -> () -> ViewController' to expected argument type 'ViewController'**

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that there is no "self" at that point in time where you want to initialize your presenter because your view controller is initialized later. You could work around this problem by declaring your presenter as lazy like this

```
fileprivate lazy var viewPresenter: ViewPresenter = {
    return ViewPresenter(controller: self)
}()
```

or you could just initialize your presenter later in viewDidLoad

```
private var viewPresenter: ViewPresenter!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.viewPresenter = ViewPresenter(controller: self)
}
```

If you ask me the best approach is (as you already did) to attach the view in viewDidLoad to the presenter.

Hope this helps.